How does one use empirical pseudopotentials to model disordered random alloys?
How does one use empirical pseudopotentials to model disordered random alloys?
I am working on modeling random alloys and came across the following paper: https://link.aps.org/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.85.085201 , that describes a procedure to construct an effective band structure, for an alloy via disordered supercell computations.
My question is with regard to the construction of the disordered potential for the alloy supercell.
The authors use the following definition (Eq. 12, some details simplified here) for the potential $V(r)$:
$$V(r) = \sum_{n, \alpha} v \ (r - R_{n,\alpha}) + v_{\alpha NL} \ ,$$
where $R_{n,\alpha}$ is the position of the $n$th atom of the lattice of type $\alpha$, $v$ is the screened atomic empirical pseudopotential, depending on the identity $\alpha$ of the atom and $v_{\alpha NL}$ is the nonlocal spin-orbit coupling potential.
Does one just use the corresponding real space pseudopotentials around the corresponding atom/unit cell?
If yes, how does one justify this, since the pseudopotentials are usually defined for an infinte lattice, and so can one just stitch together real space pseudopotentials?

If you don't get an answer here, consider to ask this on Matter Modeling SE. Please note the guidelines regarding cross-posting, though.

Yh, asking this in Chemistry S.E wouldn't be bad either.
